# Steps to adding Group permissions to a File in box

Tags: box, usergroups

I'm using Box.com with both JWT and OAuth and I can't seem to figure out how to add group level permissions to files or folders. Can anyone tell me where I go to get at that? I've looked in the UI seemingly every where and I can't seem to find the Group permissions stuff.

All I can seem to find is how to Invite emails to the file.

In the edit group/create group area i found a way to assign folders to the group. perhaps that is the maximum of the fine-grainness of the security?

Answer (score 1):

Here's info about Box File-Level Collaboration that you can only do through the api.

https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/New-file-level-collaboration-support/m-p/27106#M1297